# Clonning boot partition to a separate drive with Clonezilla

Tags: hard-drive, clonezilla, boot-partition

I am having this problem i cannot solve and I hope ill find someone willing to aid me here-
I have 2 hard drives. The 1st one (Source) has 2 partitions. !st partition has German windows xp installed and second partition has English windows xp installed.
Now i need to clone one of the windows to the ned hdd (I do that because i sometimes need to install eng and sometimes ger windows). Now to do that i use partition to partition copy with clonezilla. Everything goes ok, but one thing, pretty crucial- I cannot boot from the new hdd... I checked I want to clone bootloader, the files are there for sure because i can see them from the source drive.

Did anyone went through this kind of problem already? I would aprichiate any help.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, Clonezilla can image/clone individual partitions but it won't get the mbr/partition table in this case.  I have read you can fix that by using the original XP install disk and selecting repair, but I have never done it.  I got this information from this forum:

http://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/3225170#forum-post-41858012

And, I too am looking for a way to image the mbr and OS partitions in one go, without needing to do a windows 'repair', or imaging the full disk, but I haven't figured that out yet.  But I did submit a question to SU about this as well.  One would think a proper choice of the switches with the linux 'dd' or 'ddrescue' command would work, but I know very little about how to use 'dd' correctly.